# Merge List in Python next to the same index

Tags: python, list, merge

I have two list, i wanted to merge both the list in next to the same index with the delimiter.

```
list1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
list2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Expected result,

```
['1 - A', '2 - B', '3 - C', '4 - D']
```

I can merge both the lists using `Concatenate, append or extend` methods. But not sure to concatenate with the delimiter of every equivalent record.

Comment: `print([" - ".join(els) for els in zip(list1, list2)])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using `zip()` and list comprehension:

```
list1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
list2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']


result = [f'{i} - {j}' for i,j in zip(list1, list2)]
```

the result will be:

```
Out[2]: ['1 - A', '2 - B', '3 - C', '4 - D']
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using `zip()`:

```
[n+' - '+list2[i] for i, n in enumerate(list1)]
```

or

```
[list1[i]+' - '+list2[i] for i in range(len(list1))]
```